# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies' bs4 scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, proxy

```
#Import
from urllib.request import ProxyDigestAuthHandler, Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import SoupStrainer
import requests

#PreInit
PROXY = {"https": "54.93.88.15:9300", "https": "165.22.81.30:38244", "https": "207.154.205.135:9999", "https": "88.198.26.145:8080", "https": "144.91.86.144:3128"}
url = "https://www.ebay.de/b/Laptops-Notebooks/175672/bn_1618754?LH_ItemCondition=7000&mag=1&rt=nc&_dmd=1&_sop=1"
req = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}, proxies=PROXY)
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

#Init
with requests.Session() as c:
    all_data = []
    #Web init
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html5lib")
    #Data collection...
    print(shipping.text.strip())
```

The thing above is the relevant part to the error im getting when running the script. Where do i incorporate the "proxies" value?
Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because there is no "proxies" argument in the constructor for a Request. There's actually an example of a request using a proxy [in the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/98820250a3c9c131d3c2d57c4fc5260aebd8aa1d/Lib/urllib/request.py#L51) of the library you are using.

```
# Note assigning more than one value to a key in a dict will result in only the final value being assigned to the key
PROXY = {"https": "54.93.88.15:9300"}
url = "https://www.ebay.de/b/Laptops-Notebooks/175672/bn_1618754?LH_ItemCondition=7000&mag=1&rt=nc&_dmd=1&_sop=1"
req = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})

# Create proxy ProxyHandler
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(PROXY)
# Create opener
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
# Install opener
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: Oh, ok thanks for the answer. Appreciate it, ill look more closely next time. After trying it im getting urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>, but ill look it on the internet.

Comment: Gotta use a different proxy i guess